# How to make UIAlertView call `alertViewShouldEnableFirstOtherButton:` after making changes?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uialertview

I have a UIAlertView with a UITextField. I have connected the UIAlertView delegate and I return YES or NO in `alertViewShouldEnableFirstOtherButton:` depending on the text in the UITextField.

I need to change the text of the textField programmatically. This works as expected.

Unfortunately I don't know how to make the UIAlertView call the `alertViewShouldEnableFirstOtherButton:` delegate method so it enables or disables the other button after I changed the text of the textField.

I thought the UIAlertView registers as a target of UITextField, so I tried to send a `UIControlEventValueChanged` from the textField. Didn't work.

---

From the stack trace I figured out the delegate method is called from the private UIAlertView method `_alertSheetTextFieldDidChange:`.

So if I do `[self.currentAlert performSelector:@selector(_alertSheetTextFieldDidChange:) withObject:textField];` after changing the text, the delegate method is called and the enable state of the button changes. But, since this is a private method, the app will probably be rejected. I don't want to risk that.

---

Is there a clean way to make the alert view call `alertViewShouldEnableFirstOtherButton:`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I was on the right track with sending a control event. I just choose the wrong event.

This will work:

```
[textField sendActionsForControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingChanged];
```

Comment: I just ran into this problem as well, and this answer works and seems to be the correct way of doing it